# Why do I have to add a /128 ipv6 address explicitly to a device if I have a /64 already?

Tags: ipv6

On a Fedora server, I have the following line in my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0`:

```
IPV6ADDR=<REDACTED>:48ea::1/64
```

Now binding to that specific address works:

```
$ nc -l <REDACTED>:48ea::1 1025
```

However, binding to another address in the same netmask space fails:

```
$ nc -l <REDACTED>:48ea::2 1025
Ncat: bind to <REDACTED>:48ea::2:1025: Cannot assign requested address. QUITTING.
```

If explicitly add `<REDACTED>:48ea::2/128` (either by adding it to `IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES` or by running `ip addr add <REDACTED>:48ea::2/128 dev eth0`), then I can bind to it.

**Why adding the `/64` address is not enough?** Do I have to explicitly add every single /128 address to the device before using it?

Comment: That's just the subnet and ::2 could be any other machine in the same network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number after the `/` is the subnet size, which is (almost) always a /64 in IPv6. It doesn't say anything about your local machine. Just like with IPv4 you still have to assign each individual address to the interface.

With IPv4 you can write both `192.168.0.1/24` and `192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0`. They mean exactly the same.

With IPv6 writing `<REDACTED>:48ea::1/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::` (or even `<REDACTED>:48ea::1/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:0000:0000:0000:0000`) would become a bit unwieldy, so only the `<REDACTED>:48ea::1/64` notation is used.